# How the keyword `After` works in systemd service?

Tags: linux, systemd, services, systemd-timer

I have prepared two services a.service and b.service. The a.service run using a.timer.

a.service

```
[Unit]
Description=service a
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple

#restart on failure and tries 5 times. If fail in all, then reboot the system
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.clar/a.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=2min
StartLimitAction=reboot
```

a.timer

```
[Unit]
Description=10minute timer

[Timer]
# start this 20 Sec after boot:
OnBootSec=20

# ... and then every 10 minute:
OnUnitActiveSec=10m

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

b.service

```
[Unit]
Description=b service
After=a.service

[Service]
Type=simple

#restart on failure and tries 5 times. If fail in all, then reboot the system
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.clar/c.py
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.clar/b.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=2min
StartLimitAction=reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

As my configuration a.service will start after 20sec from boot up and b.service should run after a.service.

But in reallity b.service is started before the a.service. I have searched google and I tried by adding both `Requires=a.service` and `Wants=a.service` in b.service unit section. But neither one helped me.

I didn't understand the After working. Is there anything else to add in the configuration?

Comment: Why is `b.service` `WantedBy=multi-user.target`?

Comment: to start on reboot

Comment: But you seem to want to start it after `a.service` is started. Which is it?

Comment: without `WanteBy` b.service will start after a.service?

Comment: What is the actual flow you want?

Comment: I just want to run b.service after a.service has started.

Comment: Then you should have `WantedBy=a.service` and `After=a.service`.

Comment: The option you said " you should have WantedBy=a.service and After=a.service" is not helped me.

Comment: @muru Its not working bro.

Answer (score 1):

As muru said, You can modify it just like below.

```
[Unit]
Description=b service
After=a.service

[Service]
Type=simple

#restart on failure and tries 5 times. If fail in all, then reboot the system
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.clar/c.py
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/.clar/b.py
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=15
StartLimitBurst=5
StartLimitInterval=2min
StartLimitAction=reboot

[Install]
WantedBy=a.service
```

Then you have to do `sudo systemctl disable b.service` and `sudo systemctl enable b.service`